# How to do claim based authentication in wp7?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, sharepoint-2010, httpwebrequest, claims-based-identity

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the claim based authentication. I am using the following link to do claim based authentication in wp7 against claim based sites.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2010/10/04/developing-windows-phone-7-applications-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

In the above link I am using the uri for the authServiceUri as http://login.live.com/ and passing the appropriate username and password. I am getting the error as "javascript required to sign in. your browser does not support javascript or scripts are blocked". Can you please tell me what should I need to do to remove this error ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me. If you have any new ideas about claim based authentication then please share the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" Name="webBrowser1"/>
```